# How to get items from DynamoDB using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get items from AWS DynamoDB using getItem() method.
But there was an error - Unexpected value type in payload.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
    
    $client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
        'region' => 'eu-west-3',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'key'    => 'YOUR_KEY',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
    ));
    
    
    $tableName = 'RoamarUser';
    echo "Creating table $tableName. " . PHP_EOL;
    
    $result = $client->getItem(array(
        'ConsistentRead' => true,
        'TableName' => $tableName,
        'Key'       => array(
            'UserId' => '1001'
        )
    ));
    
    echo $result['Item']['Email']['S'] . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is very useful to put the actual error here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.
I missed the type of key that I want to get.

```
$result = $client->getItem(array(
        'ConsistentRead' => true,
        'TableName' => $tableName,
        'Key'       => array(
            'UserId' => array('N' => 1001)
        )
    ));
```